# Knob/handle to turn shower diverter valve

Tags: shower, valve, diverter

[image]
Handle for diverter valve.
The plastic has split and will no longer turn the spindle which is 5 mm in diameter with a flat. The handle/ knob does not need to look like this one. I just want to be able to turn the spindle. Can anyone help to find a replacement?

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix. You just need a [Universal Diverter Handle](https://www.homedepot.com/p/PartsmasterPro-Tub-and-Shower-Diverter-Handle-Universal-Fit-in-Chrome-Finish-58188/203051290). Home Depot has several options. Take the old one in with you and they will fix you right up or you can order online.
[image]